# Change global variable using History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I've been trying to implement History.js. I've got some understanding of how getting and pushing states work, however I'm having particular trouble with the data storing component of the history along with using global variables.

As a simple example, I decided to try and set up a script which would change the colour of a html  box upon being clicked. This would also trigger the history - essentially creating a history for clicking the box (and its colour being changed on each state of the history).

Is there any way to update a global variable based on the data (in this case, updating `i` per click) supplied in History State's data?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">CLICK ME</div>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<button id="forward">Forward</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var History = window.History;
var i = 0;

if (History.enabled) {
    var State = History.getState();
    History.pushState({count:i}, $("title").text(), State.urlPath);
} else {
    return false;
}

// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange', function(){
    State = History.getState();
    console.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    $(this).css('background-color', getColour());
});

// Trigger the change
$("#div").on("click", function() {
    i++;
    History.pushState({count:i},"State " + i,"?state=" + i);
});

function getColour() {
    var colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "aqua","blue", "purple", "magenta","black"];
    if (i > colours.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        i = colours.length - 1;
    }
    return colours[i];
}

$("#back").on("click", function() {
    History.back();
});

$("#forward").on("click", function() {
    History.forward();
});
```

I'm also using **JQuery**, **ajaxify-html5.js** and **scrollto.js** as per recommendation by other threads.

[Editable JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7HVmH/) | [Viewable JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7HVmH/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this a ton (and reading more questions), I've figured it out. I'll detail what the solution means to any others who come across this.

**[JSFIDDLE VIEW SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7HVmH/14/embedded/result/) | [JSFIDDLE VIEW SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/7HVmH/14/)**

First here's the final code. Note that the JavaScript has `document.ready` extras to get it working outside of JSFiddle.

It's also worth noting I took out **ajaxify-html5.js** and **scrollto.js** out, as they weren't needed (and were breaking the code somewhere).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="count"></div>
    <div id="colour"></div>
</div>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<button id="forward">Forward</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
button {
    width: 148px;
    height: 40px;
}

#count, #colour {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: "Consolas";
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var History = window.History;
var i = 0;
var colour = getColour();
var colourName = getColourName();

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (History.enabled) {
        changeHistory();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange', function(){  
        State = History.getState();
        i = State.data.count;
        colour = State.data.colour;
        colourName = State.data.colourName;
        changeHistory();
    });

    // Trigger the change
    $(document).on("click", "#box", function() {
        i = i + 1;
        colour = getColour();
        colourName = getColourName();
        changeHistory();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#back", function() {
        History.back();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#forward", function() {
        History.forward();
    });


});

function getColour() {
    var colours = ["rgb(220,45,45)", "orange", "rgb(230,230,50)", "rgb(15,210,80)", "rgb(100,220,220)","rgb(50,80,210)", "rgb(140,20,180)", "rgb(230,70,110)","grey"];
    if (i > colours.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        i = colours.length - 1;
    }
    return colours[i];
}

function getColourName() {
    var colourNames = ["Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Light Blue","Blue","Purle","Pink","Grey"];
    return colourNames[i];
}

// Make the changes
function changeHistory () {
    $("#colour").html(colourName);
    $("#count").html(i);
    $("#box").css('background-color', colour);
    History.pushState({count:i, colour: colour, colourName: colourName},"A Shade of " + colourName,"?colour=" + colourName);
}
```

So going back to what I wanted to achieve with the question:

- Clicking the box would add history
- Each history would hold variables required to affect global variables

Its worth noting the solution **specifically** uses variables from each iteration of the history to power the global variables, whereas the program itself uses the global variables. The variables used to power the interface **never access the ones stored in history**.

Let's break up the program into separate and simpler processes and functions. Much like other history.js solutions, there's things you require to get it working:

- **History.getState():** Gets the latest history item "from the stack"
- **History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange', function() {}:** An event listener which will trigger a function when the window has a statechange (history change in this case)
- **History.pushState({data}, title, url):** Pushes a state into the "history stack". Holds an object (data), title (of the tab/window) and url to display.

### Setting the history:

When a user clicks on the box, the program should:

- increment the counter (i)
- change the colour and colourName
- add the new history stack object in

I decided to separate the first two features from the last one. The function `changeHistory()` is responsible for updating the contents of the box (from global variables) and pushing a new history object in (using global variables).

`changeHistory()` gets called whenever I want to add a new item of history in and update the contents in the box to reflect the new history - so at launch at when the box is clicked.

When the box is clicked, the first two criteria get met. Using the existing global variables and functions, the new colour and name are retrieved and set as the global variables.

This is how it should behave:

> Box Click -> Increment i, Change variables -> Push History

### Listen for the history change:

Once a history change has been made (either by clicking the box, pressing back/forward buttons or browser buttons), a change needs to occur.

By creating the variable `State = History.getState()`, we have an easy way of accessing the data from the latest history stack object.

We'll use this data from the history object.data to assign to the global variables. After updating the variables, we'll update the view using `changeHistory()`.

This is how the model should work:

> History changed -> Update globals from history -> Update View

History change will occur whenever someone presses back, forwards or the box, accounting for all possible changes.